# How to clean up a mess of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have used VS Code on Linux, MacOS and Windows, with Settings Sync on. I noted as I started working on Windows heavily just a few months ago that my keyboard shortcuts were not working in most cases as documented. Looking at the keyboard shortcuts editor there are a huge set of System shortcuts as well as many from extensions. I was hoping there was some way for me to "backup" the shortcuts so I could clean them out and then define a limited set that might actually work and I would want to use regularly. I cannot seem to find a way to do that. I tried the JSON keybindings editor as discussed here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings . However, I only found only three there. I am sure there is a way to launch without any extensions and I could disable or uninstall them, but the large majority are system shortcuts so are not created by extensions.

I would appreciate any pointers as to how to clean up this mess. Maybe a programmatic approach is required.

One of 14 screenshots like this: [image: keyboard shortcuts example]

Comment: 1) "_define a limited set that might actually work_" what about the current ones _isn't working_ for you? " 2) _However, I only found only three there._" three what? 3) What about settings sync isn't working for you? 4) Why not just ignore all the keyboard shortcuts that you won't use? Are they somehow in your way? 5) Have you looked at [profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles)?

Comment: Do you mean that System shortcuts were different, or what?

Comment: go to your `keybindings.json` remove any.all you don't want, yes VSC has many key bindings but the ones you don't use, don't bother, if a key bind is not working use the key bind debugger to see what happends when the combo gets pressed

Comment: Thanks for the comments, each of you.

@starball 1) So many of the current definitions collide with documented ones. Nearly every documented one I try fails. 2) Three entries in keybindings.json. 3) I don't know that it isn't working, but if there is a possibility that using three different OSes has fouled up the keybindings, then I have hit that. 4) Yes, as I said above nearly every documented shortcut as a different target. 5) I guess I could create a new profile and start from scratch with all settings. Sounds like more work than I would like to do.

Comment: @Dimava - yes, system shortcuts are different but also others too differ from the documentation.

Comment: @rioV8 As mentioned, there are only three in keybindings.json, which are new ones I added. So, I can't remove more than those three. I want to go to a clean slate to define just the bindings I want and use. I would like the current set documented in such a way as I can go easily go and redefine it.

Comment: "_So many of the current definitions collide with documented ones._" Could you please give a couple examples? Like- around 10 examples?

Comment: @starball - I don't understand what help that would be. I don't keep track of them and would take me some time to find them. I just know that the last several times I have had documentation refer me to a shortcut, the shortcut does not do what the documentation indicates. Isn't it sufficient to say they exist. Now, I want a way to clear them out and start fresh.

Comment: your job as a question asker is to make your question understandable. To me, this question is not understandable without that information.

Comment: @starball Sorry you don't understand. That probably means you are not one to answer it.

Comment: @KevinBuchs how about pasting default keyboardbinding.json from this github repo https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings/tree/master in vs code json file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach would be to select a `keybinding.json` "per OS" (or, more accurately, to quickly select and switch between different `keybinding.json`, depending on your current Keyboard layout and OS).

See [**`codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings`**](https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings) as a possible implementation of that concept:

> ## # Why
>
> Code uses key combinations that are idiomatic to each platform. "Find" might be bound to F3 on Windows, but Command-F on Mac. This can be supremely annoying if you use Code on multiple operating systems, in which case it's preferable to use keyboard shortcuts that feel the same on each OS.
>
> This repo keeps an up-to-date dump of key bindings for Code on each operating system, which can be used to apply default keys for another OS, or remove Code's default keys entirely.
>
> ### How to use these files
>
> Press `F1` or `Ctrl Shift P` or `Cmd Shift P` to open the "Show All Commands" search box, then search for "keyboard" and choose "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)". This will open a new editor file containing the custom key combinations you've already configured - be sure not to overwrite these. Paste in the contents of the file you want - that's it! For example, if you're on Linux but want to use Mac keys, paste the contents of `macos.keybindings.json` into your editor.
>
> ### Unmapping
>
> The `.negative.keybindings.json` are "opposite" mappings - they remove keyboard shortcuts for a given OS. These will return VS Code to a blank slate, with no keyboard shortcuts at all, so it generally only makes sense to use these in conjunction with another keybinding file.
>
> One would typically only use these if you found yourself accidentally triggering certain actions - you may be pressing keys which normally do nothing in VS Code on another OS.
>
> For example, if you're used to working on Windows but are currently on Mac, you can apply `macos.negative.keybindings.json` (as described in How to use these files) to remove all the Mac shortcuts. Then, at the bottom of the Code keybindings.json editor, delete the bottom `]`, add a comma `,`, then paste the contents of `windows.keybindings.json`. Remove the top `[` from the pasted contents. If you've done this correctly, there should only be one set of `[` and `]` at the top level and VS Code should not complain when the file is saved.

Comment: Thanks @VonC ! This is an awesome answer. Your opening statement: "Another approach would be to select a keybinding.json per OS." So, I understand how I can use the files in the git repo to clear or define keybindings. Can you flesh out what you mean by your opening statement. Is there a way to have Code select alternate keybindings files based on the OS?

Comment: @KevinBuchs I meant that https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings could be a way to "emulate" using keybindings per OS. That plugin allows you to quickly switch keybindings, in order to select the one which fits your current OS.